# How to set a delay on Error in Angular / NgRx Subscription with Interval

Tags: angular, rxjs

I would like my `interval` to wait 5 seconds on an error before trying to hit my `service` again.  Much like it does on a successful call.

Using Angular 12 and NgRx 6, I have the following code in my `ngOnInit()`

```
    this.switchMapSubscription = interval(5000).pipe(
        startWith(0),
        switchMap(() => this.service.getData(dataKey))
    ).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.buildData(data);
        }
    );
```

When `this.service.getData()` receives an error, it retries immediately and continuously.

I have tried to put a delay in the `interval()`:

```
 this.switchMapSubscription = interval(5000).pipe(
        startWith(0),
        switchMap(() => this.service.getData(dataKey)),
        retryWhen(error => error.pipe(delay(5000)))
    ).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.buildData(data);
        }
    );
```

And in the `subscribe()`:

```
 this.switchMapSubscription = interval(5000).pipe(
        startWith(0),
        switchMap(() => this.service.getData(dataKey)),
    ).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.buildData(data);
        },
        err => err.pipe(delay(5000))
    );
```

Both of my attempted solutions gave me the same results as the original code.

Comment: That's pretty confusing. You put `err => err.pipe(delay(5000)` into `subscribe()` in order to do what?

Comment: @martin When the service called by `switchMap` gets an Error, I want it to delay 5 seconds before trying to call the service again.  My last attempt at something before asking here.

Comment: So can you show where did you put `err => err.pipe(delay(5000))`?

Comment: @martin I edited the question to better explain my two attempts at a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the error is present, you want to delay, but when it's not present you want to set back the right one.

```
this.switchMapSubcribtion = this.service.getData(dataKey).pipe(
    retryWhen(err => return err.pipe(delay(5000)))
).subscribe(...)
```